# IBAction method now shown in File's Owner

Tags: ibaction, file-ownership

I have a header file that declares two classes. The second looks like

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface MailComposerViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> 

- (IBAction)sendMail: (id)sender;
```

Then, in a xib file that is working just fine with the methods of the first class that i didn't mention, I just can't find the sendMail method when I try to pull It out from a TabBarButtonItem -not navigationBarButton- and give it to File's Owner as ususal. I tried to erase the (id)sender and switch IBAction for void in the declaration of the method, but non have worked. I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong by defining two classes in the same header that point to the same xib.

Comment: perhaps you should synthesize in your .m?